# How to store MySQL results in array of objects?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I want to retrieve data from the MySQL database and store the results in an array. The array should be of type students but am kind of stuck. I want to store the data of students in an array. (consisting of multiple students objects). Then finally I want to loop on that array of objects using for loop and output the data stored in that array using Student class getter methods. The data can be populated by the student instances using constructors or setter methods.

```
<?php 

/**
 * Student Class.
 */
class Student 
{
    //Properties.
    private $id;
    private $fullName;
    private $grade;

    
    //Constructor With Parameters.
    function __construct($id, $fullName, $grade)
    {
        # code...
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->fullName = $fullName;
        $this->grade = $grade;
    }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getFullName(){
        return $this->fullName;
    }
    public function getGrade(){
        return $this->grade;
    }



    public function setId($id){
        return $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function setFullName($fullName){
        return $this->fullName = $fullName;
    }
    public function setGrade($grade){
        return $this->grade = $grade;
    }


}

 ?>
```

**Get List From Database.**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$student = new student(0,"", 0.0);
$ret = array();
$studentArr = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["fullName"]. " " . $row["grade"]. "<br>";
    $ret[] = $row;
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}

// echo json_encode( $ret );
echo '<pre>',print_r($ret),'</pre>';


foreach ($ret as $ddd) {
    $studentArr[] = $student->setId($ddd['id']);
    echo $ddd['grade'];
}

foreach ($studentArr as $std) {
    echo $std->getId();
}
```

SQL

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `student_grades`;
CREATE DATABASE `student_grades` ;
USE `student_grades`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `student`;
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fullName` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `grade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reviewed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `student` (`id`, `fullName`, `grade`, `reviewed`) VALUES
(9,     'Andrzej Parkitny',     92,     0),
(21,    'Jane Doe',     67,     0),
(23,    'MOhamed Elliethy',     45,     0)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `id` = VALUES(`id`), `fullName` = VALUES(`fullName`), `grade` = VALUES(`grade`), `reviewed` = VALUES(`reviewed`);
```

Comment: On contrary, this is very easy in PHP.

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create an array of objects, just fetch objects:

```
$ret = [];
while($obj = $result->fetch_object('Student')) {
    $ret[] = $obj;
}
```

[Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php)

Then iterate over the array as usual:

```
foreach($ret as $student) {
    echo $student->getId();
//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be very simple to do using PDO, but if you are stuck with mysqli then you can also achieve the same with a simple loop. However, you must remember that mysqli assigns properties first and then calls the constructor. Your constructor should not change the properties anymore or it will overwrite them.

```
class Student
{
    //Properties.
    private $id;

    private $fullName;

    private $grade;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM student";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$arrayOfStudents = [];

while ($student = $result->fetch_object(Student::class)) {
    $arrayOfStudents[] = $student;
}

// or in one line:
while ($student = $result->fetch_object(Student::class) and $arrayOfStudents[] = $student);
```